# R saves invalid encoding into SQL Server nvarchar column

Tags: r, sql-server

I'm trying to save text into SQL Server using R and `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. I have this simple script:

```
test <- data.table(dbGetQuery(con, "select LOCATIONNAME from LOCATION where LOCATION = 'AT2331'"))

name <- test[, LOCATIONNAME]

sql <- paste0('INSERT INTO LOCATION_TEST (TEST) VALUES (\'', name, '\')')

dbGetQuery(con, sql)
```

The data in the original table is `VÖSENDORF` and it's shown properly in R, but the result in the database is `VÃ–SENDORF`. The column type is nvarchar and server collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. How can I fix this?

I also tried

```
sql2 <- iconv(sql, from="UTF-8", to="UTF-16LE")
```

But that says:

> embedded nul in string

**Edit:**

Using 'N' prefix doesn't change the result:

```
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO LOCATION_TEST (TEST) VALUES (N'", name, "')")
```

If I use just a hard coded value, it works fine:

```
sql <- paste0("INSERT INTO LOCATION_TEST (TEST) VALUES (N'VÖSENDORF')")
```

This is RStudio in Windows. Output of `Sys.getlocale()`:

> "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"

Tested my code in Linux with following locale, and there it works fine:

> "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"

Tested with the latest R version, `4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)` and the same issue still continues.

Comment: SO is a .NET application storing Unicode text in `nvarchar` fields. This isn't a SQL Server issue. `nvarchar` is UTF16.  Unicode strings must have the `N` prefix, eg `N'VÖSENDORF''. Instead of using a prefix though, a *far* better solution is to use parameterized queries. In these queries the values are passed as strongly-typed parameters outside the query itself removing the risk of both SQL injection *and* type conversions

Comment: I've also tested using `...VALUES (N\'', name, '\')')`, and the result is the same

Comment: What is the actual query though? What you wrote is part of a string concatenation expression. What is the resulting query? And what would happen if `name` was `'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS;--` ? The [Run Queries Safely](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/) article shows how to use parameterized queries and avoid such problems completely. You end up with simpler and *faster* code too. Plus, the parameterized query can be reused by setting different parameter values

Comment: This is the complete query that I've narrowed the issue into. Yes I know about sql injection, but there's no user input at all. The whole thing is a 300 .R file mess that I've inherited, and definitely can't start with re-writing everything.

Comment: You cant not to. First of all, you *have* to check what the actual query is. Chances are it's not what you expect. `paste0("INSERT INTO LOCATION_TEST (TEST) VALUES (N'", name, "')")` isn't a string, it's a command that concatenates strings. And `name` is the input that causes the problem. Your own edit shows that the problem is caused by this concatenation

Comment: `paste0("INSERT INTO LOCATION_TEST (TEST) VALUES (N'VÖSENDORF')")` does nothing but return the original string. This means that the actual problem occurred when concatenating the two static strings with `name`. For some reason R treated the UTF8 string as ASCII. Are you running on Linux perhaps? With a single-byte encoding in LC_ALL instead of UTF8?

Comment: So, why does it get broken then if it's just a string concatenation? R shows it to be `"INSERT INTO LOCATION_TEST (TEST) VALUES (N'VÖSENDORF')"`. And this is RStudio in Windows.

Comment: Where did this string come from? A file? Windows is natively Unicode - all strings are Unicode. Non-Unicode applications use the codepage corresponding to the user's locale though when reading files or handling text. R and RStudio used to do that but this was fixed about 10 years ago. On the other hand, many Unicode languages (including Python 3 and .NET Framework) will use the user's locale when opening text files, unless those files start with a Byte-Order-Mark.

Comment: It's coming from SQL Server, from nvarchar column. That's the first row in my code.

Comment: `LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252` is exactly what will force R to treat strings as single-byte Latin1 instead of UTF8. The `1252` codepage is telling R to treat any text as a sequence of Latin1 bytes. That's why `Ö` is treated as `Ã–` - that's how the UTF8 bytes look if handled as Latin1. `Ã` in particular is the first byte in the range 0x80-0x7FF

Comment: Has UTF-8 support in Windows been only from R 4.2 onwards, which has come out few weeks ago -- and I'm still in 4.1.3. https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2021/12/07/upcoming-changes-in-r-4.2-on-windows/

Comment: Or at least I can't seem to find any UTF-8 locale for windows that  `Sys.setlocale` would honor.

Comment: Try *removing* all attempts at "fixing" the locale. I don't know what that blog is trying to say because it's simply not true. No matter who wrote it. I struggled with R's inconsistencies about 10 years ago and I actually dove into the C++ code. Which uses wstring when compiled on Windows, string when compiled on Linux. And Windows uses UTF16, not UTF8. UTF8 as a locale codepage is an experimental setting even on Windows 11. And yet, the very page you see proves there's no problem with Unicode. That's why I can write Αυτό Εδώ

Comment: I haven't attempted to fix the locale before you pointed it out. So, what should I actually then do to get this working?

Comment: Better question is why you are concatenating strings in the first place. You should be passing parameters. SQL injection is not just about *security* it's also about *correctness*

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, like I said, I know this should have been done differently, but I cannot just start re-writing code made by someone else that I know nothing about. So the question I'm asking is, how to fix this. And that's of course not what the actual code is, it concatenates stuff all over the place, so it's definitely not a simple change.